# How to Call All Function from one File and then Move to other File Again Call the Functions using getattr function in Python

Tags: python, function, getattr

suppose I have two files File1.py and then File2.py and the Multiple Functions Written in the Files, and then I have the main.py file where I am calling the File1.py functions using getattr builtin function. after reading one by one function of the File1.py now I want to call the File2.py Functions.

File1.py

```
def function1():
    print('function 1')


def function2():
    print('function 2')

def function3():
        print('function 3')
```

File2.py

```
def function1():
    print('function 1')


def function2():
    print('function 2')

def function3():
        print('function 3')
```

main.py

```
import File1
import File2
'''
here I want to call Both File Functions One By one simultaneously Using getattr function.
'''
```

Comment: Less prosa, more code. [ask] & [mre]. [edit] your question and add context instead "suppose"s.

Comment: "here I want to..." I don't understand the description. What should *happen* as a result of doing this? "Using getattr function" Okay, so you have some idea of the tools that you expect to be useful here. Did you read the documentation? Did you try to write the code? What went wrong?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, actually I implemented the Code using only 1 File. I am working on A application where previously more than 1K functions were written in a single file and call by the getattr function.  now, actually, I want to break down this too large file into multiple small files where I can debug them easily and improve the Application code complexity.

Comment: Please edit the question. Better grammar helps tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I got your question correct usually it helps if you show a bit of example code. But I believe the runpy function does what your asking for

> import runpy
> runpy.run_path(path_name='Module_you_want_to_run.py')

And you will get a dict as output with all global variables of that module

Comment: Why spend that effort when you already imported it, thus can just call dir() on the modules?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply enumerate the module's attributes.

```
from inspect import isfunction
def call_all(module):
    for name in dir(module):
        if name[0]=="_": continue
        fn = getattr(module,name)
        if isfunction(fn):
            fn()

call_all(File1)
call_all(File2)
```